# How to make angular2 routing work with express router?

Tags: angular, express, heroku, angular2-routing

I was trying to host my express rest service with an angular2 app on the same server.
After reading varies related post I found varies solutions all worked on local server **http://localhost:3000** but when hosted my app on Heroku and I try to access my express route starts with /api/... all worked well. but not able to access angular2 UI page it started showing a Not Found message on the page.

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`[TRACE] Server 404 request: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

or

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

or

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

or

```
app.get(/^\/([^a]|a[^p]|ap[^i]|api[^/]).*$/,(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: What does "I try to access my express route starts with /api/... all worked well. but not able to access angular2 UI page it started showing Not Found message on the page." mean? What is not working?

Comment: Its not showing my angular2 app login page.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to guess what the error is based on the info that you've given. Please share your folder structure and your routing details and maybe your heroku url if it's not private

Comment: I found the problem when i push my app to heroku git. Its not uploading dist directory that contains angular2 app compiled build to the heroku server. I found answer in your question.

Comment: So problem solved? Awesome.

Comment: Yes. Thanks bro.

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question and accept it as the solution so that the issue can be seen as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I deployed my app on hosting server I found that dist directory does not get deployed on a server which contains Angular app build that gets created after running **ng build --prod**.

Firstly I manually uploaded it to the hosting server and my app started working correctly. Then it came to my mind it will be a manual task for each time so I found two solutions for this problem.

1. First, remove /dist entry from a .gitignore file that means it will not ignore dist directory when I will push the app to any hosting server.
2. Second I read package.json documentation from this link **https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts** and get to know about preinstall and postinstall scripts and updated my package.json file to have following scripts.

   ```
   "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "node index.js",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e",
      "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
   },
   ```

read this article for deployment on heroku  https://paucls.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/deploy-angular-2-cli-app-to-heroku/